# namespace and extern 'C' compilation errors

Tags: c, c++11

I have tried to google the errors but to no avail. Maybe I am searching in the wrong direction. 
I am trying to compile a file but when i tired to compiled it, the compiler gave me these errors:

C2059 syntax error: ';' 
C2059 syntax error: '}' 
C2061 syntax error: identifier 'namespace_name' 
C2449 syntax error: found '{' at file scope (missing header?)

In my code.c file:

```
#ifndef myclass_c
#define myclass_c

#include "classA.h"
#include "classB.h"   
#include "conversionLib.h" // no namespace is being used here

namespace namespace_name {

// ... generated codes in C....
}
#endif
```

In classA.h and in classB.h:

```
#ifndef myclassA_h // myClassB_h if in classB
#define myclassA_h // myClassB_h if in classB

#include "classC.h"  // both classA and classB include classC.h

namespace namespace_name {
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// ... generated codes in C....

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
}
#endif
```

and in classC.h (same for classD.h)

```
#ifndef myclassC_h // myclassD.h for classD.h
#define myclassC_h // myclassD.h for classD.h

#include "classD.h"  // no includes in classD.h

namespace namespace_name {
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// ... generated codes in C....

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
}
#endif
```

what am i doing wrong? or have i missed out something? 
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. 
I apologized if this question/format is confusing. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need the `extern 'C'` for?

Comment: These codes are generated codes. The codes generated is in C and I need to use these in codes in c++ environment. 
I need to modify these codes by adding in namespace to avoid redefinition of functions/variables in the solution.

Comment: First of all, the code you posted doesn't reproduce the issue. Secondly, `extern "C"` (note the `"`, not `'`) does not do what you think it does (in particular, mixing namespaces and `extern "C"` won't work).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes, i know of the ". It was a typo. Have edited it. Before i added in the namespace, all was fine and compilable. But after i add it in, it gave me these errors. Btw, im using VS2010, win 7 if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem seems to be, that you use c++ syntax in a `.c` file.
C does not support namespaces!

It does not make much sense to put a `extern "C"` function into an namespace. in C++ the compiler does something called 'name mangeling' it actually puts the name space (e.g. the class name, the namespace) and additional information (like function or template parameter) of an identifier into its symbol name that is the input to the linker.

`extern "C"` tells the C++ Compiler not to do so. so you lose the binding to the surrounding namespace (as well as the possibilities to overload the function).

It may be a nice thought to put the functions in a special namespace if they are included from C++ but on the other hand mostly in C namespaces are build y using a special prefix to the function name. so in C++ you end up with the explicit c++ name space and the implicit function prefix name space.

If you still want a namespace in c++ around your C-Functions you have to include the namespace definition into your `#ifdef __cplusplus` blocks. (but i do not even know if this is allowed by the C++ standard)

Comment: I added the namespace definition in the block and remove the namespace definition in the code.c file. And it compiles! Thanks! Somehow the code.c do not need the namespace definition,even when it uses the namespace's variables

Comment: @Kai the question is: Does it also compile in a c++ environment

Comment: Yes, it compiles in a c++ env